# Can you guide me about dedicated AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I aim to host all e-mails from the company on AWS but I am not sure which service I have to use.

I am trying to find the exact service.

Can your friends guide me please about which service I have to use and can you guide me regarding the service's price?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[Amazon WorkMail](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/) is the hosted business email and calendar service, with pricing [here](https://aws.amazon.com/workmail/pricing/).

Not to be confused with [Amazon Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/) which is a service that allows developers to send email e.g. transactional email for marketing and other purposes.

Comment: This is indeed the case but I would urge OP to do more research in to other providers to decide which to use before you pick one of them.

Comment: Think about, we have total 2 TB storage about sending and receiving of emails process monthly. We already hired dedicated server but can aws be cheaper then we currently use hosting company. That's why, if I find exact aws service that everything is gonna be clear for us in terms of cheap or expensive.

Comment: I’m not sure what your question is, but you can read the pricing information online.

Comment: @jarmod how much money for hosting mail server on aws and which service is used for it?

Comment: @questionmark Stack Overflow is not the place to get current pricing information. If nothing else, it will be out of date quickly. All AWS service pricing is available on the web.